# Finding if a cell contains 1 of 2 words, then return yes or no in a different cell

Tags: excel-formula

trying to use this formula:
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"yes","no")

Except I want to check not only "apple", but also "pear"
tried to embed OR formula variously, but cannot make it work.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pear",A1))),"yes","no")`

If you want it to say yes only when one of apple and pear are present, but not both, then you can use XOR instead:

`=IF(XOR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pear",A1))),"yes","no")`

This is a bit hard to maintain if you later want to add a third word, so an alternative is to use an array formula (After entering the formula, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have Excel evaluate it as an array formula):

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"apple";"pear"},A1))),"yes","no")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! First one worked perfectly, didn't try this combination myself! So I'm gonna use it for now, but I will try the other ones too.